# Line showing same record for iteration?

Tags: linq

I have a simple line query

```
        var areaList = _db.vwArea
            .OrderByDescending(q => q.Qualifier)
            .ThenBy(r => r.Id)
            .Take(topnareas.Value)
            .ToList();
```

and then

```
        foreach (var record in areaList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(record.Area);
        }
```

Iterates through the 200 or so different areas.  All Ids are different.

Yet my output looks like:

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
....
```

Each Id should be different

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AAAD
....
```

The view it's pulling from looks fine.  It returns the data as it should.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The issue is that we have no idea what's in `_db.vwArea`. I suspect it has duplicates. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Nope.  No duplicates.

The view is like this:

Area
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AAAD

Comment: If you are sure the view is working correctly then please remove the SQL server tag as it won't be part of the problem

Comment: Sorry, I thought I only had the Linq tag on it.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  Even though the data all looked correct, the PK wasn't bubbling up.  As a matter of fact, while the PK is in the base table, it was not in the view, therefor EF didn't know what the PK was.  As Linq was interacting over the list, it didn't change to the next record until I set an Entity Key in the model.   As soon as I did that, it started iterating like it should.